# How can I generate entities from oracle database in intellij idea?

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-data-jpa, persistence

I have a problem about create entity from oracle database.
When I'm creating entities from database I got error(unable to resolve 'String').
I search a lot but I can't get normal way for solve this problem.
I want to notice, I get this error for only varchar2 column convert to String.
I added image the below.
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you check your JDK
i faced with can not resolve String but not in this section
and the problem was that i dose not configured JDK

Comment: You're right.Thanks.
I do it file -> invalidated caches / Restart.